# How to use (re/)CAPTCHA with R/Shiny?

Tags: r, shiny, captcha, recaptcha

Say you have a simple app on https://lalaland.shinyapps.io/mail-form/ that functions as a contact form. You want to test that the sender is not a bot before an email is sent. This could look something like:

**global**:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyAce)
library(mailR)
```

**ui.R**:

```
ui<-shinyUI(
      fluidPage(  

              fluidRow(
                    column(2
                           ,textInput("contact_name", "Name*", placeholder = "Ed Snow") 
                    ),
                    column(2, offset = 0
                           ,textInput("contact_email", "Email*", placeholder = "eddie@lubyanka.com")
                    )
              ),
              fluidRow(
                    column(4,
                           aceEditor(outputId = "contact_message", value = "...", fontSize = 13)
                    )
              ),
              fluidRow(
                    column(2,
                           checkboxInput("contact_not_a_robot", "I'm not a robot*", value = FALSE), # !!! <---
                           actionButton("contact_click_send", "Send")
                           ))
      )

)
```

**server.R**:

```
server <- shinyServer(function(session,input, output) {

      observeEvent(input$contact_click_send, {

            if( is.null(input$contact_click_send) || input$contact_click_send==0 
                || !input$contact_not_a_robot){ # !!! <---
                  return(NULL)
            }

            send.mail(from = "kremlin@gmail.com",
                      to = "trumptower@gmail.com",
                      subject = "Shower time!",
                      body = input$contact_message,
                      smtp = list(host.name = "smtp.gmail.com"
                                  , port = 465
                                  , user.name = "kremlin@gmail.com"
                                  , passwd = "DONALD_BIG_HANDS123"
                                  , ssl = TRUE),
                      authenticate = TRUE,
                      html = TRUE, send = TRUE)


            # reset form
            updateTextInput(session, "contact_name",  value = "")
            updateTextInput(session, "contact_email", value = "")
            updateAceEditor(session, "contact_message", value = "Message sent succesfully!")
            updateCheckboxInput(session, "contact_not_a_robot", value = FALSE)
            updateActionButton(session, "contact_click_send", icon = icon("check"))
      })

})
```

The question put a different way: how does one weave (re/)CAPTCHA into this R/Shiny contact form?

Comment: There are packages available on GitHub to do this. 

reCAPTCHA v2 - https://github.com/carlganz/shinyCAPTCHA
reCAPTCHA v3 - https://github.com/sarthi2395/shinygCAPTCHAv3

Comment: @SiddharthArthi Great, I'll have a look. Anything on [CRAN](https://cran.r-project.org/) though? And some step-by-step guide/documentation?

Comment: I am afraid we do not have a package in CRAN for this. What version of reCAPTCHA are you planning to use? I can help based on that.

Comment: @SiddharthArthi Putting it on CRAN is of course encourageable. A full, detailed, step-by-step answer for v3 would be very welcome.

Answer (score 0):

For reCAPTCHAv3, use https://github.com/sarthi2395/shinygCAPTCHAv3

```
devtools::install_github("sarthi2395/shinygCAPTCHAv3")
```

Add this this to your **global.R**:

```
library(shinygCAPTCHAv3)
```

**ui.R**:

```
ui<-shinyUI(
      fluidPage(  
               GreCAPTCHAv3Ui(<your site key>,"homepage","responseReceived"),

               #Rest of your code
               )
           )
```

where you will have to enter your *SiteKey* generated in reCAPTCHA admin console for the domain that you have registered. Here, I have specified the *action* as 'homepage' but you can choose the one that fits your purpose (https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/v3).

*responseReceived* is the object that we would be using here to pass the token received to shiny server for validating back with Google.

**server.R**

```
server <- shinyServer(function(session,input, output) {

      observeEvent(input$responseReceived, {
                   result <- GreCAPTCHAv3Server(<your secret key>,input$responseReceived)

                  if(result$success){

                     #Rest of your server logic.

                     }
            })

})
```

Here you will have to enter your *SecretKey* generated in reCAPTCHA admin console for the domain that you have registered.

If everything goes well, when you fire up your web page, you will see the reCAPTCHA box on the right hand bottom corner. Hope this helps.